# How can I embed my latest Facebook and Instagram posts in a Vue.js website

Tags: vue.js, facebook-graph-api

While I was able to embed twitter posts very easily, Facebook and Instagram seems not so.

Please I need a guide on how to embed **all** my latest Facebook and Instagram post**s** in a Vue.js website.

I've gone through their documentation, but still unable to.
I could have managed the steps using a token, and design my interface, but the **token expires after 1 hour**.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Good option...But this is not exactly what I'm looking for. This is a site open to any one who can view my posts in here...This means they can do that from any browser, any time, day or month long. Thanks once again.

Comment: _"But this is not exactly what I'm looking for."_ - then what actually is? You complained about the short token lifetime. So I referred you to the solution for _that_.

Comment: I just want to embed posts from timeline - view only, something similar to twitter-for-websites: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview

I'm not handling anything server-side. Plus, there are Caveats with using long-lived token.

It's a one-time work with little or no maintenance. But here, token expiry is conditional  and if expired, it breaks (as seen in the documentation)
On this basis, I'm put off. Link below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/%20access-tokens/debugging#expiredtokens

Comment: Then pretty much your only option is to use the Page plugin, with the timeline tab showing - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin A plugin to embed single posts also exists, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts - but with that one you explicitly need to specify the post URL, and if you wanted to _automatically_ get the URLs of your x latest page posts, you'd have to go the API route again.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot @CBroe. that was what I went with. I'll just need to set up privacy for review, and trust it works.